# Change pure SQL database query to WordPress post query?

Tags: query, query-posts, sql

I am trying to query posts that are nearby a given (lat/long) location. I have found this working SQL query, but this won't provide me flexibility to alter the queried later on, since I am not really into plain SQL. Is there a way to transform the SQL database query below to a normal WP post query?

Here is my SQL statement:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["cityLat"])) {     
            //FUNCTION
            global $wpdb;
            $lat = $_POST["cityLat"];
            $long = $_POST["cityLng"];
            $searchname = $_POST["searchname"];
            $distance = 20;
            $nearbylocs = $wpdb->get_results( 
            "SELECT DISTINCT    
                city_latitude.post_id,
                city_latitude.meta_key,
                city_latitude.meta_value as cityLat,
                city_longitude.meta_value as cityLong,
                (6371 * acos(cos(radians( $lat )) * cos(radians( city_latitude.meta_value )) * cos(radians( city_longitude.meta_value ) - radians( $long )) + sin(radians( $lat )) * sin(radians( city_latitude.meta_value )))) AS distance,
                wp_posts.post_title
            FROM 
                wp_postmeta AS city_latitude
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta as city_longitude ON city_latitude.post_id = city_longitude.post_id
                INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = city_latitude.post_id
            WHERE city_latitude.meta_key = 'city_latitude' AND city_longitude.meta_key = 'city_longitude' AND post_title LIKE '%$searchname%'
            HAVING distance < $distance
            ORDER BY distance ASC;"
            );
    
    
    if($nearbylocs){
          foreach ($nearbylocs  as $nearbyloc ) {
                echo $nearbyloc->post_title;
          }
    }
}
```

What I want is something like:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'fields' => 'all',
    'lat' =>  $distance['lat'],
    'lng' =>  $distance['lng'],
    'distance' => $distance['range']
);

$query = new WP_Query_Geo( $args );
```

Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: "Is that possible?" No. Or it might. You can create a function that in the end will execute the custom query, this might abstract it enough for you right now. But you will need a custom query, since (as far as I know) no native method can handle the geo stuff and you can't easily expand them to do so.

Comment: Hi, thanks for clarifying that! Any idea how I can extent the above SQL query to filter posts by custom terms in custom taxonomies? See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/401453/change-sql-get-results-to-search-for-posts-with-custom-term-in-custom-taxonomy

Thanks!